# Small SVG imageview looks blurry or "curvy"

Tags: android, imageview, android-vectordrawable

I have generated a vector asset (based on an own svg file) via Android Studio.

The layout code of my image view:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_drink"
        android:layout_width="21dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_smoothie_icon" />
```

The issue is, that this **small version of the image looks "curvy" or blurry.** Below is a screenshot with increased size (so you can see the cury edges of the images).

[image]

My compileSdkVersion is 28 and minSdkVersion is 21.

I tried to solve this with the use of the following:

- imageview: android:scaleType="fitXY"
- imageview: app:srcCompat instead of app:src
- build.gradle: vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
- tried different sizes within the asset xml

**What could cause this issue?**

**EDIT:**
This is the content of the svg (image is based on a file from freepik.com):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="-318 422.4 85.6 122.6" style="enable-background:new -318 422.4 85.6 122.6;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <path d="M-232.4,445l-6.1,100h-49.9l-6.1-100h20.7c-0.6-5.7-1-9.9-1.1-11.7c-0.3-4.8-1.6-6.1-2.1-6.5c-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.6-0.9-0.6
        l-0.3-0.2H-318v-3.1c0,0,14.6-0.5,26.9-0.5c8.4,0,15.8,0.2,16.8,1c2.3,1.8,3.7,4.8,4,9.8c0.1,1.8,0.5,6.1,1.1,11.8L-232.4,445
        L-232.4,445z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Vector xml:

```
<vector android:height="12.3dp" android:viewportHeight="123"
    android:viewportWidth="86" android:width="8.6dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#000000" android:pathData="M85.6,22.6l-6.1,100h-49.9l-6.1,-100h20.7c-0.6,-5.7 -1,-9.9 -1.1,-11.7c-0.3,-4.8 -1.6,-6.1 -2.1,-6.5c-0.4,-0.3 -0.9,-0.6 -0.9,-0.6l-0.3,-0.2L0,3.6v-3.1c0,0 14.6,-0.5 26.9,-0.5c8.4,0 15.8,0.2 16.8,1c2.3,1.8 3.7,4.8 4,9.8c0.1,1.8 0.5,6.1 1.1,11.8L85.6,22.6L85.6,22.6z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: `Log.d` the value of `ImageView.getDrawable()` (or `ImageView.getDrawable().getClass()`), what do you see?

Comment: The result is "class android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable". Or do i missunderstand you?

Comment: the same if you use `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`?

Comment: Is this picture a print screen on the desktop or is it from a real device?  Because if this is on the emulator then it will probably be fine on a real device since the density will be a lot greater on the real device the anti-aliasing will look a lot better.

Comment: please put your svg detail here.

Comment: @pskink yes, is the same

Comment: @Mihai the pipcture is from a real device

Comment: i heard that native `VectorDrawable` (not from support lib `SupportVectorDrawable`) had on some platform versions such bugs - it was android 5.0 or 6.0 i dont remember correctly

Comment: @MasoudMokhtari i just added the svg code to the main post

Comment: why don't you use a vector instead of the svg .I believe your svg gets rasterized at the wrong size and that's why you get that weird effect. For better compatibility use the vector tag and make your viewport 24.0 x 24.0 and the width and height 24dp, this way everything scales nicely with the density.

Comment: I actually use a vector xml. The above is just my base-file, which i have converted within android studio.

Answer (score 2):

Here i have made your vector using more scale friendly dimension and angles and remember that we can't draw half a pixel there will be anti-aliasing involved but we can mitigate by tweaking out shapes. when working with vector and animated vectors you can use [shape-shifter](https://shapeshifter.design/) to edit your path and make it android friendly or even animate it.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24.0"
android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <path 
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M9,21L7,6L12,6C12,6,12.013,4.071,12,3.5C,11.987,2.929,12.081,3,11.5,3,L4,3L4,2C4,2,11.505,2.006,12,2,C12.26,2.015,12.506,2.125,12.691,2.309,C12.875,2.494,12.985,2.74,13,3L13,6L18,6L16,21Z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: Please provide more details on how to use the tool.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're running up against the limits of how smooth a sloped line can look, at low resolution. The blurriness is due to [anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing#Examples), which is an attempt to smooth out the jagged edge that would result from using only black or white pixels.

If you want to reduce the "curvy" effect, you can try changing the slope of the sides of the cup. Since your cup sides are almost vertical, there are a few large "steps" on each side, so the curviness is more noticeable. Make them completely vertical, or more slanted. A vertical line will have no steps. A more slanted line will have more steps, but smaller ones, so they should be less bumpy.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is because of scaleType. Of course your vector width and height have problem too. Please try this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_drink"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_smoothie_icon" />
```

Comment: This is a good point, that Jan's `android:scaleType="fitXY"` will often result in stretching, distorting the aspect ratio, which could contribute to the problem. However the two images he showed side by side are in the same aspect ratio, suggesting that the aspect ratio is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On my side moving to ConstraintLayout instead of using LinearLayout or FrameLayout removes the blurry quality on vector drawable.